# What means "in mitigation"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Here is the sentence: **In mitigation, I am on the move and posted this from an internet cafe.**
I didn't quite grasp the sentence.As I know *In mitigation* means *make something appear less serious*.But that doesn't match here

Comment: Is [this site](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/Internet_cafe.html) the source? Please [edit] your post to include the source and the surrounding context.

Comment: No.That's not.I got it from an example.

Comment: Without further context, any answer is going to be primarily speculation, but it seems likely this is a rather awkward way (and **not** one I'd suggest using, mind) of saying 'In my defence..." (e.g. "Yes, my post contained some errors, but in mitigation, I am on on the move and posted this from an internet cafe.")  Definitely sounds strange, though.